# Finding a certain white space?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, whitespace

I need to find a certain whitespace with regex. I need to find and replace whitespace or multiple whitespaces only if it's before or after a new line and the other whitespaces should remain.

Now i'm using this to remove multiple whitespaces:

```
preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $string);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Any particular regular expression syntax?

Comment: No, I don't know regular expressions, but i just don't want to have whitespace and newline together. I'm not sure if regular expression is needed to do this, but i'm just guessing.

Comment: the answer I was after was "PHP" in this case (which is Perl compatible)

Answer (score 7):

Just use the [`m` (multiline) modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) so that `^` and `$` match the start/end of a line.  Then you can write a pattern like this:

```
preg_replace('/^\s+?|\s+?$/m' , ' ', $string);
```